# MVC 5 PartialView update with AJAX not updating View?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm in the process of getting my head wrapped around using AJAX to update a portion of an MVC View using some conditional logic. I posted the question earlier and was pointed to using PartialView to build out the whole HTML table and then pass that back to the View.

That lead me to use this article and an example.
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/asp-net/revisiting-partial-view-rendering-in-asp-net-mvc/

I then pulled out my table code and put it in a Partial View. All that worked just fine. However, now I'm trying to update with AJAX and the actual updating of the database is working but the updating of the View is not.

In other words, when I click on the "Test" button in the code below I can see it going to the HttpPost in the controller as well as seeing the database being updated. However, the page doesn't get updated. I have to refresh the page again to see the change.

I'm betting it has to do with the @Html.Partial call in the View but I'm not figuring out what I need to do to fix it.

From what I've read it sounds as though when I make the AJAX call and it returns the HTML it should replace everything in side of my DIV.

Here is what I have in my View. Upon initially viewing the page the @Html.Partial is populating the table as expected.

```
<div id="exceptionTable">
    @Html.Partial("_DailyLogExceptionsTable", Model.listExceptions)
</div>
```

Here is my AJAX call. I can see the values coming through. The RID is the record ID and the arg would be a static value of either "A" or "D" depending on which button they will click.

```
function ApproveDeny(rid, arg) {
    var url = "/Exception/ExceptionApproveDeny/";
    $.post(url, {rid:rid, arg:arg})
    .done(function (response) {
        $("#exceptionTable").html(response);
    })
};
```

This is my ActionResult which updates the database through the DAL. Then I create a new ViewModel, call get the new list of Exceptions, and then call the PartialView again passing it the new list of exceptions.

```
public ActionResult ExceptionApproveDeny(int rid, string arg, string shift) 
{
    try
    {
        DAL.ExceptionApproveDeny(rid, arg);

        var vm = new ExceptionLogDailyTableViewModel();
        vm.listExceptions = DAL.GetEmployeeExceptionsByDate(CurrentEmployeeId, DateTime.Parse(shift));

        return PartialView("_DailyLogExceptionsTable", vm);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //error code
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a 200 OK from the ajax call ? Check the browser dev tools ->Network tab. Also are you sure you are passing the correct type to the partial view in your action method ? (the type of vm is same as what the view is strongly typed to?)

Comment: Thanks, that's getting me closer. I'll get better at using the Dev Tools the more I use them. Since I'm kind of new with AJAX, I end up forgetting to look through the Dev Tools. It did help me find and error with one of the parameters being passed in to the controller ActionResult. I'm still getting an error but hopefully I'll be able to narrow that down soon. I'll post back here once I get it or if I have any more questions with it. Thanks!

Comment: @Shyju...Thanks for the help. I was eventually able to work through my errors and get this to work. I definitely need to learn how to debug with AJAX better but at least struggling some is getting me a better understanding of how it works. Now I have to change up my code even more since I was just asked to put in a modal for a confirmation along with the ability to add some comments in the database call and then update only the table on the web page using AJAX.